# Calling function from view in angularJS = bad performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've noticed that if I call functions from my angular view, the functions are called a lot. Also when the data hasn't changed.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days_array">
   {{getWeek(day)}}
</div>
```

Then getWeek() gets called for all the items in days_array every time almost anything in the application changes. So I wondered if this is what filters are solving? So filters are only called when days_array is actually changed, and therefore gives better performance?

Comment: filters are for exactly what they sound like, *filtering* and returning a subset your data.  in your case, you probably want to use the bind once syntax, i.e. `{{::getWeek(day)}}`, or better yet, add the week as a property to the day when the data is fetched.

Comment: If you'r days_array doesn't change bind this one with bind once `ng-repeat="day in ::days_array"`

If you're fetching data from server, just set days_array to undefined, so it just gets evaluated when its realy filled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would not be easier to optimize to `map` week once and use it directly in HTML? In some place you load days:

```
$scope.loadDays = function () {
    service.getDays().then(function (days_array) {
        $scope.days_array = days_array.
    });
}
```

Or you have it hard-coded:

```
$scope.days_array = [{index: 0, code: MONDAY}...];
```

You can easily add `week` property:

```
$scope.days_array = $scope.days_array.map(function (day) {
    day.week = getWeek(day);
    return day;
});
```

And use it in HTML like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days_array">
   {{day.week}}
</div>
```

And it performs as usual Angular binding.
Moreover, you can optimize it further - if `week` never changes you can use one-time binding:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days_array">
   {{::day.week}}
</div>
```

Angular *forgets* about checking this variable. And even one more step - if `days_array` is set once and never changes, you can *forget* about list at all:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in ::days_array">
   {{::day.week}}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's bad performance. Filters would help, yes. If you can have a way when something is added to know if it's newly added.

I will leave this link with performance tips on angularjs loops

https://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/

I hope it helps.

Comment: I would imagine that the loop if the array has 5 objects, will create 5 elements. 

If after you add +1 element, it will create 6 elements again. And this is bad.

I would also imagine the filter would make it, depending on the filter, less elements, so less performance impact. That was my point. If functions are the same or not, I never said anything about it.